# Java Spring omits fields when making a JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

```
public class ConnectedEntry {

    private EntryInScores scores;
    private EntryInValues values;
    private String someString;

    public ConnectedEntry(EntryInScores scores, EntryInValues values) {
        this.scores = scores;
        this.values = values;
        this.someString = "Adasd";
    }
```

I have an object that looks more or less like this, and I use it as a GET response for my API. `scores` and `values` are both database entities. I wanted to add a String to the response with some additional information.

What happens is that the objects are properly turned into a JSON and they show up in the response, but the string is omitted, with no error: it's just not there.

I tried wrapping the string in a wrapper class, but it didn't help.

What could I do?

Comment: Does the string field have a getter?

Comment: "More or less" may hide some important differences. Show your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Spring uses Jackson as the default converter from objects to JSON. In order for Jackson to convert to JSON you must provide getters, so that Jackson can get and convert those values. As I can see in your representation you don't have any getters. Try providing getters for the fields that you wish to convert. Never make fields public!

Answer (score 0):

You can go for creating json object and put the data as key value pair to resolve this issue.

Happy Coding!!!